# Facebook iOS SDK - Authorize via new Facebook Mobile App returning "authorize#error=unkown_error"

Tags: facebook, ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

Using latest github version of FB iOS SDK in my iOS app which previously worked fine authenticating with the Facebook app installed. Now in iOS 5 and using the new facebook mobile iOS app the url returned to my application is fb://authorize#unkown_error.

Has anyone encountered this. I verified that iOS SSO is enabled in my app in the facebook dev portal. I also tried creating a new facebook app from scratch and using that in my iOS app and it garnered the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that I feel this is a solution but if I force the authorization to happen via Safari it works fine.

Comment: It also happens in my case. Forcing authorization to Safari helps, but is noa a solution. Please post it here when you find the cause.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to use Facebook SDK as it was on 4 nov 2011 and complete the tutorial you will run into trouble as mentioned above, because it does not yet implement ARC. If you want to use Storyboarding as well you run into the trouble that the appDelegate now has a slightly different scope. You should not, as the tutorial states, make the appDelegate you respond to Facebook delegate methods but you should doe this in the rootViewController.

I posted a code whit a fix on gitug: git@github.com:doozMen/Facebook-SDK-in-iOS5-and-using-storyboarding.git

Answer (score 0):

in Xcode 4.2.1 when adding the src folder according to the tutorial , you need to include it fully without removing the project file , but on the add files popup you need to to deselect the add to target. then in your linkage build rule add the resulting static library of Facebook to the build target and not the source itself. in that way Facebook compile as is and can be used with or with out ARC/SB .